# Application compiled with XCode 12.3 will not launch on M1 Chip machine

Tags: macos, xcode12, apple-m1

I am a developer who develops on 10.15.7 on an Intel-based MacBook Pro for Mac OS 10.12.2 - 11.1.   I do not have an M1 machine to test with. I have a program that I compiled as a universal app using XCode 12.3.  A user with an M1 Mini reports that it will not launch.  It shows in Activity Monitor as running, but I know it did not run because it did not produce a debugging file I added to it to test.  If I compile it for the development machine (i.e. not universal), it still does not launch.

If I compile the exact same project—with NO changes— in XCode 11.7, it runs perfectly on the Mini in Rosetta mode.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Same for me, I could not find a fix